# Como fazer com que um modal dispare e permaneça no rodapé/parte debaixo da página?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, front-end

O Modal, por padrão dispara de cima e para no topo. Quero fazer o inverso. Que ele dispare da parte debaixo e permaneça ali (na parte debaixo/footer/rodapé). Alterei o top dele, porém no mobile a posicionamento fica incorreto.

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"> ABOUT </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        CONTEÚDO
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Penso que a tua solução seria fazer o seguinte:

Através do JQuery podias fazer um código deste tipo:

```
    $('.btn').click(function() {
        $('.modal')
            .prop('class', 'modal fade')
            .addClass( $(this).data('direction') );
        $('.modal').modal('show');
    });
```

E depois adicionar isto no css:

```
    .modal.fade:not(.in).bottom .modal-dialog {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 25%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 25%, 0);
    }
```

E por fim adicionar um botão no html:

```
    <a class='btn btn-primary btn' data-direction='bottom'></a>
```

De resto, é só fazeres alterações possíveis dependendo do que quíseres

## Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vaiandrept4/gamge71q/1/

Comment: Com algumas modificações, consegui o que queria através deste link: http://jsfiddle.net/6br6L7zz/

Comment: Fico feliz !!! :)